# How to trap the Window minimizing event?

Tags: java, swing, system-tray

I want to create a `JFrame` instance and on the click of its `minimize button`, I would like to hide it to the `System Tray` which is usually the `taskbar` of windows.

I'd come to know that by using `SystemTray` class in `java.awt` package I can do so but neither I'm getting any tutorial on it nor any working program example.

I'd asked this question here to either get the link to tutorial site for `SystemTray` class or if any body knows how to trap the window minimizing event, a working example.

Comment: maybe both link will help http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html and http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will trap the window minimized event and will create a tray icon. It will  also remove the window from the taskbar and it will add a listener on the tray icon so that a mouseclick would restore the window. The code is a bit scrappy but should be good enough for your learning purposes:

```
public class Qwe extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Qwe qwe = new Qwe();

    qwe.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
            if (e.getNewState() == ICONIFIED) {
                try {
                    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon("/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/emotes/face-plain.png").getImage());
                    trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            qwe.setVisible(true);
                            SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(trayIcon);
                        }
                    });
                    SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
                    qwe.setVisible(false);
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    qwe.setSize(200, 200);
    qwe.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `WindowListener` interface and `JFrame`'s `addWindowListener()` method should help you determine when the frame has been minimised.

Answer (score 2):

best way would be create follows

1) [SystemTray](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/)

2) add `JPopopMenu` to the `SystemTray's Icon`

3) set `DefaultCloseOperation` for [TopLevelContainer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) (in your case [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html))

- by using [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`
- in other cases always works `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);`
- notice don't forget declare `System.exit(1)` to the `SystemTray's JpopupMenu`, from `JMenuItem` or another `Action/Event`, because in this form currenet JVM never gone from Native OS until PC power-off or restart

Answer (score 1):

```
private void windowStateChanged(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
    // Use getExtendedstate here.
}
```

- [`WindowStateListener` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html)
- [`Frame.getExtendedState()` docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getExtendedState%28%29)

Comment: is there any example on `Sun/Oracle`'s tutorial site?

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {@Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
});
```